# Flutter RiverPod notifier not updating my AsyncValue list

Tags: flutter, riverpod, asyncvalue

I am having trouble with riverPod notifiers and having them update my UI. I have created a list view that can display the notifier build method but when an item is added, it does not update. After searching through the docs and stackoverflow I cannot see where I am going wrong. I have included the full files so you can see if I have missed anything out.

**Provider**

```
// joined_festivals.dart
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:findyourevent/models/festival/festival.dart';

part 'joined_festivals.g.dart';

@riverpod
class JoinedFestivals extends _$JoinedFestivals {
  @override
  Future<List<Festival>> build() async {
    return [];
  }

  void addFestival(Festival festival) async {
    final previousState = await future;
    state = AsyncValue.data([...previousState, festival.copyWith()]);
    print(state);
    ref.notifyListeners(); // attempt to notify listeners
  }
}
```

NOTE: The print on addFestival prints what I expect. The old state + the new festival

**List view**

```
//my_schedule.dart
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class MySchedule extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MySchedule({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final AsyncValue<List<Festival>> joinedFestivals =
        ref.watch(joinedFestivalsProvider);
    print(joinedFestivals.value);
    return switch (joinedFestivals) {
      AsyncData(:final value) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            itemCount: value.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FestivalCard(
              openFestival: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          FestivalInformation(festival: value[index]))),
              festival: value[index],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      AsyncError() =>
        const Center(child: Text('Oops, something unexpected happened')),
      _ => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    };
  }
}
```

NOTE: The print always prints the result of build()

Comment: Where are you calling addFestival?

Comment: I call addFestival in another file with `
 ref
                            .read(joinedFestivalsProvider.notifier)
                            .addFestival(widget.festival);
`

Comment: Yeah, the rest of your code doesn't have any obvious errors.  If you're on the riverpod discord, I suggest reposting there.

Comment: Oh... oh oh oh.  JoinedFestivals is not keepalive.  If someone's not watching it, it resets.  Does that help?

Comment: YES! that works now as expected!

Comment: I moved that to an answer so you can resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the original comments, you apparently confirmed my suspicion that your provider was not marked "keepAlive", and being recycled when not watched.

Just putting this here so you can mark it as the answer for future queries.